# Short for "contact address" in French

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire

Is there a shorter translation to “contact address” other than “l'adresse à laquelle nous pouvons vous contacter”?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Laissez nous vos *coordonnées*, et nous vous répondrons !

*Vos coordonnées* fait référence à une indication (un numéro ou une adresse) qui peut correspondre à n'importe quel moyen de communication (mail, téléphone, envoi postal, etc…).